# Discrete math - Prove that a tree with n nodes must have exactly n - 1 edges?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I'm new in discrete math. Can someone prove **simply** that **a tree with $n$ nodes must have exactly $n - 1$ edges**. I have researched the solution but I haven't founded yet. I know of course, a tree with n nodes must have exactly n - 1 edges. But, I can't prove it. Thank you. induction on $n$

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see that any tree with $1$ node has $0$ edges. Now let's assume that any tree with $k$ nodes has $k-1$ edges. Now, given any tree with $k+1$ nodes there must exist at least one leaf. Remove a leaf and the connecting edge. The resulting tree has $k$ nodes and by our induction assumption it has $k-1$ edges. Hence, the tree with $k+1$ nodes must have $k$ edges. And from induction, we have the result.

Comment: I think a slightly difficult technical point is to prove that every tree with more than $1$ node has at least one leaf (in fact it has at least $2$ leaves). It is intuitively obvious, but that does not really help.

Comment: If there is no leaf, then there must be cycle and it is not permitted for trees!

Comment: @chandu1729: That is indeed a way to prove that every tree must have a leaf, but the argument still has to be made.